# Install Craft 3 in public folder

Tags: install

Is it still possible to install all of Craft 3 in a public folder? Like you could with Craft 2. If it is, how do I do it?

Comment: When you say install in a public folder, do you mean you want the `vendor`, `config`, `storage`, `templates`, etc. to all live inside of your public HTML folder?

Comment: That was correct. But the server administrator has changed things so I no longer need to set it up in that way.